# django-allauth login_redirect page with username as slug

Tags: django, django-urls, django-allauth

I am using Django 3.2 and django-allauth 0.44

I have set my LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in `settings.py` as follows:

> LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile-page'

in `urls.py`, I have the following route defined:

> path('accounts/profile/slug:username', AccountProfileView.as_view(), name='profile-page'),

When I log in, (unsurprisingly), I get the following error message:

> NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
> Reverse for 'profile-page' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/profile/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

How do I pass (or specify) a parameter of the logged in user's username to the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` should point to the page on which user lands after he successfully logs into your website, unless he was redirected to the login page by trying to visit any of the pages that require the authorization.

If you want to redirect user to a specific page, in this example to his own profile page, you can create an intermediate URL that will redirect the user to his own profile page, when visited. It can be accomplished like so:

Using class-based views:

```
class CurrentUserProfileRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('profile-page', kwargs={'username': request.user.username})
```

or using function-based views:

```
@login_required
def current_user_profile(request):
    return redirect('profile-page', username=request.user.username)
```

Next, register this redirect view as a regular view, not requiring any parameters, and set the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to this view's name.

Answer (score 2):

If your view needs to perform redirects which are not very simple, you need to override the `get_success_url` method, considering that you use django-allauth, you will need to override `allauth.account.views.LoginView` and also write your own url pattern for it so that your overriden view is used. First override the view:

```py
from django.urls import reverse

from allauth.account.views import LoginView as AllauthLoginView
from allauth.account.utils import get_next_redirect_url


class LoginView(AllauthLoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.user = form.user # Get the forms user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        ret = (
            get_next_redirect_url(self.request, self.redirect_field_name)
            or reverse('profile-page', kwargs={'username': self.user.username})
        )
        return ret
```

Next wherever you define the urls for allauth, just add your own url before it:

```py
from path_to.view_above import LoginView # Change this import properly


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(), name="account_login"),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Another alternative solution using allauth is to use a custom `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` and override it's `get_login_redirect_url` because `LoginView` will internally call it in case there is no `next` parameter. To do this, first inherit from `allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter`:

```py
from django.urls import reverse

from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter


class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        return reverse('profile-page', kwargs={'username': request.user.username})
```

Next in `settings.py` set `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`:

```py
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "path.to.MyAccountAdapter"
```

Comment: I get the following error message after making the changes you suggested: **NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Reverse for 'profile-page' with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/profile/(?P<username>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']**

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli edited, do check, also added an alternative which might be more simpler in the end.

Comment: @AbduAzizBarkat Thanks! that worked. Do you know why your first solution didn't work (couldn't match the URL name)?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli it appears that the `form_valid` method of allauths `LoginView` works somewhat opposite than normally, it _first_ get's the success url by calling `get_success_url` and _then_ logs the user in so `self.request.user.username` didn't work.